# Harnack's inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ be harmonic on $\{|z|<1+\epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $u \geq 0$ on $\{|z|=1\}.$ Could anyone advise me how to show $\dfrac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}u(0) \leq u(z) \leq \dfrac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}u(0) \ ?$

I'm trying to make use of the fact that $\begin{align} u(a)=\int^{2\pi}_{0} \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{1-|a|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-a|^2}u(e^{i\theta})d \theta\end{align},$ for any $a \in \mathbb{D}$ and $u :\overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is harmonic in $\mathbb{D} \ $.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Maximum principle, $u\geq0$ on $\mathbb{D}$.
$$u(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta\leq\frac{1-|z|^2}{(1-|z|)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta=\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}u(0).$$
The last identity follows from the mean value property of a harmonic function.
The proof of another inequality is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Maximum modulus principle asserts that $\text{max}_{|z|=1}|u(z)|= \text{max}_{|z| \leq 1}|u(z)|.$ How does this mean that $u(z) \geq 0, \forall |z| < 1  \ ?$ Please advise.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. Just use the maximum principle. A harmonic function attains its maximum and minimum on the boundary.

Comment: It does. Since $u$ attains its minimum on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, while $u\geq 0$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. So $u\geq 0$ on  $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that your solution does not make use of the fact that $u \geq 0$ on $\mathbb{D} = \{|z|<1\} .$

Comment: I do use it in the derivation of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}u(e^{i\theta})d \theta  \leq\frac{1-|z|^2}{(1-|z|)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta.$