# Show that if $u_n (z_0) \rightarrow 0$ for some $z_0 \in D$, then $u_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $D \subseteq \Bbb C$ be a connected open subset and let {$u_n$} be a sequence of harmonic functions $u_n: D \rightarrow (0,\infty)$. Show that if $u_n (z_0) \rightarrow 0$ for some $z_0 \in D$, then $u_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$.

Could some one tell me which part of knowledge or which theorem to use here?

Comment: Think Harnack's inequality.

Comment: A duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304630, but neither question has a formal answer.